# How do l load a csv from a class/def function, and how do I then make it read/print both rows and columns?

Tags: python-3.x, csv, class, printing

I have a utils.py and a main.py. In the utils.py file I want all my data load, formula defs and so on. I want to create a class Data_load() and make that ensure load of data I can pull directly from main.py.

I have this:

utils.py:

```
def readMyFile(filename):
    file = []

    with open(filename) as csvDataFile:
        csvReader = csv.reader(csvDataFile, delimiter=';', )
        for row in csvReader:
            file.append(row[0])

        return file

file = readMyFile('C:\\...\\count_all_terminate.csv')

file_load = pd.DataFrame(file)
```

Got this:

main.py reads (one column only and with no header??!!):

```
              0
0     User Name
1        146166
2        146166
3        146166
4        146166
...         ...
3987     200589
3988     194018
3989     194449
3990     174565
3991     175440
```

I wanted main.py to read this:

```
              0    col 2    col 3    col n  
0     User Name
1        146166
2        146166
3        146166
4        146166
...         ...
3987     200589
3988     194018
3989     194449
3990     174565
3991     175440
```

How do I

1. place the def in class, something like the following...

   ```
    class Data_load():
        def __init__(self, ....):
            self


        def readMyFile(filename):
            file = []

            with open(filename) as csvDataFile:
                csvReader = csv.reader(csvDataFile, delimiter=';', )
                for row in csvReader:
                    file.append(row[0])

                return file
   ```
2. ..and how do I make it print all the columns I know to exist in the 'count_all_terminate.csv' file? Any help is appreciated, Happy New Year from Hubsandspokes

Comment: It looks to me like the reason you are just getting 1 column is because of the line ```file.append(row[0])```, I imagine you can get all columns if you chage the line to ```file.append(row)```, but can't be sure unless you provide a sample of your csv  file.

Comment: Not sure you want to make the data load into a class, leaving it as a function seems pretty straight forward, unless you plan to have multiple operations which alter the data be performed on the same file.

Comment: You're exactly right, itprorh66. Starting out with the data load def, I continue the utils.py file with more operations. Thx, btw, for solving the column issue. Very simple solution. Next step in my class set up would be EDA, then doing some stats, so that I have a def readMyFile, def EDA, def Stats. If you have a suggestion for the EDA and stats defs, I am all ears. BR Hubsandspokes

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use a class, I would employ pandas.  You could do it standalone as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame.read_csv(filepath, **kargs) #see docs for **kargs definitions
df_stats = df.describe()  #Provides summary statistics on each column see docs for 
                          # description
```

If you desire a class,

```
class Data_load: 
    def __init__(self, filepath, **kargs):
        self.df = pd.read_csv(filepath, **kargs)

    def summary_stats(self):
        return seld.df.describe()
```

Then to use:

```
filepath = r"path to csv file of interest"
myData = Data_load(filepath)  
EDA = myData.summary_stats()
```

Comment: Hi, itprorh66, I did succeed in applying your suggested solution to a class context, yet pls take a look at the ticket: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65538649/how-do-i-organise-my-class-file-in-python