# How do I integrate def common_stats into class Data_Load?

Tags: python-3.x, function, class

A newbie, I am trying to increase familiarity with OOP, building a class structure to allow for a more organized way of coding. I have several files in my structure, *formulas.py*, *df.py* and *main.py*, and a *test.py* file. Basically, I am therefore targeting elimination of test.py and df.py. Also, in *class Data_Load*, I have *get_EDA_shape, get_EDA_describe and get_EDA_info*. These are also redundant, and should be replaced by the functionality presented in *def common_stats()*.

Now I want to integrate with/make a part of the formulas.py class Data_Load:

1. *def common_stats()* in the *class Data_Load* hierarchy

formulas.py (I know that it shows the same twice which is what I am trying to reduce):

```
import pandas as pd
from df import df

class Data_load:
    def __init__(self, df):
        self.df = pd.read_csv(df, delimiter=';')

    def get_EDA_info(self):
        return self.df.info()

    def get_EDA_describe(self):
        return self.df.describe()

    def get_EDA_shape(self):
        return self.df.shape


def common_stats(df, name): # How do I make this def part of the Data_Load class?
    df.name = name
    print('#{}\n'.format(df.name))
    for col in df.columns:
        # Stats
        print('\nStats')
        print('#{}\n'.format(col))
        print('\nvalue_counts')
        print(df[col].value_counts(dropna=False))
        print('\n')
        print(df.columns)
        print('\nsort_values')
        print(df[col].sort_values(ascending=True))
        print('\nisnull')
        print(df[col].isnull())
        print('\nisna')
        print(df[col].isna())
        print('\ndescribe')
        print(df[col].describe())
        print('\ndtypes')
        print(df[col].dtypes)
        print('\nshape')
        print(df[col].shape)
        print('\nnunique')
        print(df[col].nunique())
        print('\nunique')
        print(df[col].unique())
        print('\nisnull().sum()')
        print(df.isnull().sum())



def get_details(self):
    return self.common_stats()

if __name__=='__main__':
    common_stats(df, name='Analysis')
```

df.py:

```
import pandas as pd

df_ = r"C:\\...\\Python data\\test_line_ADFS.csv"

df = pd.read_csv(df_, sep=';',
                  usecols=['col1', 'col2', 'coln'])
```

...and main.py

```
import warnings
warnings.simplefilter(action='ignore', category=FutureWarning)
warnings.simplefilter(action='ignore', category=DeprecationWarning)
warnings.simplefilter(action='ignore', category=RuntimeWarning)
warnings.simplefilter(action='ignore', category=UserWarning)


# from formulas import file_load
import pandas as pd
from formulas import Data_load
from formulas import common_stats, get_details
from df import df_, df


myData = Data_load(df_)
EDA_stats_1 = myData.get_EDA_shape()
EDA_stats_2 = common_stats(df, name='Analysis')


print("\nEDA_stats_1")
print(EDA_stats_1)

print("\nEDA_stats_2")
print(EDA_stats_2)
```

test.py - Also, how do I make this def part of the Data_Load class in formulas.py?

```
import warnings
warnings.simplefilter(action='ignore', category=FutureWarning)
warnings.simplefilter(action='ignore', category=DeprecationWarning)
warnings.simplefilter(action='ignore', category=RuntimeWarning)
warnings.simplefilter(action='ignore', category=UserWarning)

from df import df

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np  # for declaring an array

count = df['count'].astype(int)

def mean(count):
    n = len(count)
    mean = sum(count) / n
    return mean


def variance(count):
    n = len(count)
    mean = sum(count) / n
    deviations = [(x - mean) ** 2 for x in count]
    variance = sum(deviations) / n
    return variance


def stdev(count):
    import math
    var = variance(count)
    std_dev = math.sqrt(var)
    return std_dev


print("Variance of the sample is % s " % (variance(count)))
print("Standard Deviation of the sample is % s " % (stdev(count)))
print("Mean of the sample is % s " % (mean(count)))
```

Sample data (unique date=date of unique logon). Some students have more observations over time => several logons:

```
             unique date  User Name       Start to_date
1    2020-01-06 00:22:00     192421         E19 2020-08-31   
191  2020-05-21 08:41:00     193203         E19 2020-12-09   
146  2020-05-20 17:51:00     193537         E20 2020-12-08   
321  2020-05-22 20:19:00     193203         E19 2020-12-09   
339  2020-05-23 09:02:00     193203         E19 2020-12-09   
...                  ...        ...         ...        ...   
927  2020-05-29 21:19:00     165156         E20 2020-06-08   
1051 2020-05-31 20:48:00     165156         E20 2020-06-08   
88   2020-05-20 06:15:00     184806         E19 2020-05-26   
239  2020-05-21 18:59:00     195350         E19 2020-05-25   
547  2020-05-25 19:39:00     200580         F20 2020-05-26
```

Comment: You are asking multiple questions here.  I am unsure as to exactly what you are asking,. Please simplify your question to one main point, Include a sample of your input dataframe to provide context, and explain what you want to do.  For example, focus on the question of 'How do I include the function common_stats into my class?" As written, your question will not get good answers.

Comment: You're right. Let me start with the one question you correctly suggest. Thx

Comment: Now I refined the question, being more/directly specific w/r to integrating def common_stats in the class Data_Load hierarchy, thx for your kind support

Comment: Can you provide a small sample of the dataframe you are working with, also please explain as clearly as possible what you are trying to accomplish with the common_stats.function. If you could illustrate what you want using your sample dataframe, it would help me understand.

Comment: Ok, thx for your kind co-operation..;o) First, my objective is 1) to create an overview of the data I am working with and 2) deliver more descriptive statis on the data, e.g. various groupby combinations. Ultimately, I want--as step 3 and 4--to deliver mean, median, std related to specific columns, e.g. time_diff, to_date (termination of enrollment), etc. to see details about logon frequencies for particular student lines like bachelor and diploma students. I am gonna deliver a sample of the data set asap, thx again - rgds, hubsandspokes

Comment: Hi, itprorh66 - digged into a way (that could probably be optimised further), but got something, integrating the common_stats with the parent file. Now I want to visualize some of the stats, yet encountering with new issues. This time, my question is very specific..;o)...BR Hubsandspokes - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65580088/how-do-i-make-my-plot-show-simple-input-as-loaded-from-another-class-file